# running specific tagged serenity tests when I have tags in the CucumberTestSuite

Tags: tags, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I have a serenity framework set up with a CucumberTestSuite file with the following:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    tags = "@test",
    plugin = {"pretty"},
    features = "src/test/resources/features"
)
public class CucumberTestSuite {
}
```

Then in each feature file I tag the scenarios with @test and when I run mvn clean verify all of the scenarios that are tagged @test run. I want to add smoke tests for certain environments so I thought I could add @smoke to the scenarios and run only the smokes by calling

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke"
```

but, unfortunately, all the tests seem to run. Is there a way of running only specific tags while the CucumberTestSuite has a tags in its @CucumberOptions or must I remove the tags from the file and always call the tests via

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke"
```

or

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @test"?
```

A

Comment: I guess No, you have to remove `@test` in CucumberTestSuite to statisfy your need.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at the wrong advise. I saw many posts saying I use

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke"
```

but as I said above this leads to all tests being run. Instead use:

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke"
```

and this will run only tests tagged with smoke

A